# Probability of exponential of normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

**Problem :**
Let $Y$ is normal random variable with mean of $10$ and a variance of $100$.

If $X=e^Y$, Compute $P(e^{10}<X<e^{20})$.

---

**My Attempt:**

Since $X=e^Y$, rewrite probability : $P(e^{10}<e^Y<e^{20})$.

Since a map $x \to e^x$ is bijective, $$P(e^{10}<e^Y<e^{20}) = P(10<Y<20)$$

Then substitute $Z=\frac{Y-10}{10}$, then $Z$ is standard normal random variable and
$$P(10<Y<20) = P(0<Z<1)$$

Finally with normal table,
$$P(0<Z<1) = \Phi(1)-\Phi(0) \approx .3413 $$
where $\Phi$ is CDF of standard normal distribution.

Is my attempt correct? If not, what should I modify?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me! However, just because a function is bijective doesn't mean you can take that step. It should be monotone increasing/decreasing.

Consider this bijective function:
$f(1) = 0, f(2) = 10, f(3) = 9, f(4) = 8$

$f(1) < y < f(3)$ does NOT mean
$f^{-1}(f(1)) < f^{-1}(y) < f^{-1}(f(3))$
$1 < f^{-1}(y) < 3$
because we could have taken $y=8, f^{-1}(y)=4$, for example.

Comment: I agree that the derivation is correct and that bijectivity is not sufficient. It would be slightly better to require *strict* monotonicity, I think - though strictness follows from bijectivity, of course. I also want to add that, for strictly decreasing sequences, the inequality signs would flip.